# How can i get the date from my database and put it on query

Tags: php, mysql

[image: this is my database]

the name of the table is sms_in

I would like to get sms_text using send_dt
so i tried dis query

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT  `sms_text` FROM `sms_in` WHERE 'sms_dt' = 2015-01-13");
```

but it doesn't show any result can anyone help me I'm new in query.

I'm trying to get the data for my website

sorry for the typo it's 'sent_dt' in my query not 'sms_dt'

Comment: Remove single quotes from sms_dt

Comment: `sms_dt` = 2015-01-13  \\ mysql_* is deprecated please use mysqli_*

Comment: just add single quotes '2015-01-13'

Comment: @habbib I've done that but doesn't get me any result either

Comment: i've answered ur question.. check it.. look what @Arun commented  about mysqli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this**

Add single('') quote to date value not in date field:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT  `sms_text` FROM `sms_in` WHERE sms_dt = '2015-01-13'");
```

And also while seeing your table structure I found that there is no field with **'sms_dt' name** , there is one date filed whose name is **'sent_dt'**  So please try with that field like:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT  `sms_text` FROM `sms_in` WHERE  sent_dt = '2015-01-13'");
```

I hope it will works work you !

Comment: @Ram I am glad I could help you! thanks for accepting my answer. please vote it up also it will increase my ranking little more thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

first of all use mysqli instead mysql version. and if type of sms_dt is text then u should use single quotes''

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT  sms_text FROM sms_in WHERE 'sms_dt' = '2015-01-13'");
```

Comment: is it ok if i use that even the date is datestamp?? how can i say this the date comes from sms messages date with the format YYYY-MM-DD, is it a text or object??

Comment: Remove single quote on `sms_dt` and put backticks for that

Answer (score 0):

Use quote of your column value don't column

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT  `sms_text` FROM `sms_in` WHERE `sent_dt` = '2015-01-13'");
```

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks) may help you

Comment: None i'm just troubleshooting it in mysql query database and it says 0 rows selected

Answer (score 0):

Hello brother use single quotes for the date

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT  `sms_text` FROM `sms_in` WHERE 'sms_dt' = '2015-01-13'");
```

Answer (score -1):

try to enclose your search criteria in single quotation: if your column is date type  column `sent_dt` then your query should like

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT sms_text FROM sms_in WHERE sent_dt = '2015-01-13' ");
```